# How can i show ngx-spinner until my whole data is loaded in Angular

Tags: angular, ngx-spinner

I have on every page header - image and text. Somoetimes the images are loading slow, the text is showed and after 1-2 seconds the heeader image shows up where it should which is not good user experience. How can i show my ngx-spinner until whole data in my component - loaded as route is comleted?

**what i tried - app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';

import {
  Router,
  // import as RouterEvent to avoid confusion with the DOM Event
  Event as RouterEvent,
  NavigationStart,
  NavigationEnd,
  NavigationCancel,
  NavigationError
} from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-app';

  loading = true;

  constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService, private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((e: RouterEvent) => {
      this.navigationInterceptor(e);
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.loading = true;
      this.spinner.show();
      console.log(1111);
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.loading = false;
      this.spinner.hide();
    }
    // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the spinner in case a request fails
    if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
      this.loading = false;
      this.spinner.hide();
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.loading = false;
      this.spinner.hide();
    }
  }


}
```

**app component html**

```
<ngx-spinner bdColor="rgba(51,51,51,0.8)" size="medium" color="#fff" type="ball-scale-multiple">
  <p style="font-size: 20px; color: white">Loading...</p>
</ngx-spinner>
```

but it is not working. I don't get the spinenr while my routes are chaning and while the compoenent is rendered there

Comment: Where is the loading data functionality?

Comment: The ngx-spinner has show - hide method which makes that under the hood.

Comment: I mean, where is the function that load data, you want to show spinner meanwhile data is loading.

Answer (score -1):

Try using lifecycle hooks for this. with the use of router events we can't define component is fully loaded or not. for this situation you can **ngAfterViewInit** life cycle.

Check the following site as reference

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks